# Can't figure it out why there is always value null

Tags: android

Trying to make a button takes captures a picture and displays it in imageview. I am saving that image temporary to have better quality. Camera doesn't work but nothing is showing on imageview

```
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.l_sliuzas.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && requestCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bitmap bitmapas = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapas);
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: which value is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO` is a `requestCode` and `RESULT_OK` is `resultCode`. But inside `onActivityResult`, you are evaluating both with `requestCode`. Which is not correct.

So below code is not correct

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && requestCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bitmap bitmapas = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapas);
    }
```

Change it to

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bitmap bitmapas = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapas);
    }
```

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท See **`resultCode`**

Comment: @PankajKumar This is a public community pal. I meant by what is the difference between codes here is it needs some explanation at least. Anyways, + 1 for added explanation.

Comment: @PankajKumar The OP *deserves to know* what is the differences between those codes at least. I'm calm, hey! :) Just wanted you to add more details, that's all.

Comment: Yes I got. I new it had to be resultCode but for some reason I couldn't see it. Thank you in a million